# Imaging a Linux Lab

Tags: linux, deployment

I am running Xubuntu on my computers in one of my labs. What is the best way to image my master image out to approximately 20 computers? Right now I am just using clonezilla and physically removing the drives to a imaging PC.  Looking for a more efficient way. Thanks

Comment: No need to remove the drives. Clonezilla can send the images to the client, even to many clients at once. That should make it easier. Anyway, in its current form the question is too broad, there are many, many ways to do parts of that (say `nbd`, clonezilla, `ssh` mounting the server's `/home/partimag` on the local computer,...).

Comment: I will investigate further. Thanks for the help!